# What is most efficient way to validate data types of columns in csv file?

Tags: pandas, csv, types

I have a csv file containing rows as records. I want to make sure that my CSV columns contain data of same data-type. Currently I do this using following method :

I import the csv using `pd.read_csv('path/to/csv', dtype={"c1" : int, "c2": str})`, so if the column contain data of different type, the error is thrown. However, this approach has two major problems.

(1) I have to read the entire csv in the memory.
(2) The row with incorrect datatype is not detected.

Reading the csv in memory is not the problem right now for me, since csvs are not huge in size. I'd like to know if there is any better way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve your issue is to open the file without type checking, then lazily iterate through the file one line at a time, and finally check if that line is valid or malformed as you need.
For example:

```
for chunk in pd.read_csv('path/to/csv', chunksize=1):
    try:
        print(chunk.astype({"c1" : int, "c2": str}))
        # or do whatever you want with the line
    except ValueError:
        print("Malformed row found!")
```

Comment: yeah, edited about `dtype` instead of `header`.